# React and NextJS: How can i detect the Location of my Client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, next.js

I have created a Website using NextJS and React. I want to provide the Website in several languages. To achieve this, I wanted to create in the `page` folder, subfolders, for example for the English language `/en`, for the German language, `/de` etc.

When a visitor then opens my Website, the correct subfolder is selected based on the public IP:

Example:
Request comes from America : the `/pages/en` folder is selected,
The request comes from Germany : the `/pages/de` folder is selected etc.

How can I do that? Since I have little experience in NodeJS environments, please show me concrete examples, many thanks...

I already have a `server.js` file. Maybe I can use this yes for it too...

```js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const request = require('request')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
    .then(() => {
        const server = express()

        //parse application
        server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

        //parse application/json
        server.use(bodyParser.json())

        server.post('/', (req, res) => {
            addEmailToMailChimp(req.body.email, (error, response, body) => {
                // This is the callback function which is passed to `addEmailToMailChimp`
                console.log(response);
                try {
                    var respObj = {}; //Initial response object
                    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                      respObj = { success: `Subscribed using ${req.body.email}!`, message: response.body };
                    } else {
                      respObj = { error: `Error trying to subscribe ${req.body.email}. Please try again.`, message: response.body };
                    }
                    res.send(respObj);
                  } catch (err) {
                    var respErrorObj = { error: 'There was an error with your request', message: err.message };
                    res.send(respErrorObj);
                  }
            });
        })

        server.get('*', (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res)
        })

        server.listen(3000, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
        })
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
        console.error(ex.stack)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/roryrjb/iplocation

Comment: This is a good article to get you started: https://medium.com/@adeyinkaadegbenro/how-to-detect-the-location-of-your-websites-visitor-using-javascript-92f9e91c095f

Answer (score 0):

Use Next.js Internationalized Routing feature.

For [Sub-path Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#sub-path-routing)

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en-US', 'fr', 'nl-NL'],
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
  },
}
```

For [Domain Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#domain-routing):

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en-US', 'fr', 'nl-NL', 'nl-BE'],
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',

    domains: [
      {
        // Note: subdomains must be included in the domain value to be matched
        // e.g. www.example.com should be used if that is the expected hostname
        domain: 'example.com',
        defaultLocale: 'en-US',
      },
      {
        domain: 'example.fr',
        defaultLocale: 'fr',
      },
      {
        domain: 'example.nl',
        defaultLocale: 'nl-NL',
        // specify other locales that should be redirected
        // to this domain
        locales: ['nl-BE'],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Follow https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing for more details.